# How to ensure single entry in database with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a table for `featured_posts`, which `has_many` `posts` to keep featured posts in the front page of the website. Now I want to ensure that I am creating only one entry at `featured_posts`. Looking for something like singleton model entry that can be stored in database. What is `rails` way to ensure that?

Since this is going to be an one entry table, I think my database overhead will be huge, is there any better way to store this type of single entry?

Comment: The way I'd do this is to just have an is_featured boolean column in your posts table and in my validator, ensure there's only one with this as true.

Comment: @hd1 thanks, I am dropping this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do this is to just have an is_featured boolean column in your posts table and in my validator, ensure there's only one with this as true -- for example:

```
class model < ActiveRecord::Model
  validate :validate, on: :create
  def validate(record)
    errors.add('Maximum of one featured post') unless  model.find(:is_featured => true).length == 1
  end
```

Comment: Also to eliminate the headache of accounting for null, e.g. if you want to fetch the opposite of true, it might be advisable set a default value of false at the database level via a migration on this boolean

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

**featured_posts_controller.rb**

```
def new
    if featured_post.empty?
        # create featured_posts
    else
        redirect_to featured_posts_path
        # or you can throw an error
    end
end
```

---

Another way is to ensure that no one can access the new and create method:

```
def FeaturedPostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :check_post_presence, only: [:new, :create]

    private
    def check_post_presence
        redirect_to featured_posts_path if featured_post.exists?
    end
end
```

---

Finally you can create a default featured post on seed and remove the new and create method altogether by adding the data in `db/seeds.rb`:

```
featured_post = FeaturedPost.create title: "Default Posts"
```